# most simple way to switch instances of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

I have many instances of same activity.
Let the stack at the moment is A1->A2->A3->A4->A5, with A5 in the top.
The code I launching ever next activity is like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("some option", "its value");
intent.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);  
startActivity(intent);
```

I need to have opportunity to bring to front every instance from any instance. For example I want to resume(!) A2. And it will be very good if it is possible to reorder activity stack, I think it is the most simple way if it's possible.
I think the using flags is not the most simply way, and they can not solve the problem fully.
I want to make class for easy switching instances, but I want to do it manually for the first.
I tried many ways.. here is one.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A2, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

A2 is static variable of my activity class (type - Activity). It contains pointer to my A2 instance. A have also A1 - A5 variables like A2.
I have added Log.e to onResume function. And I see that my code brings to the front A5 instead A2 (without log it looks like my code does nothing).

Help me please :)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to have so many instances of the same class? Although what you're trying to do should be possible, it does not seem like it would be a best practice scenario.

Comment: BMo, makes a good point. You should really not have several instances of the same activity.  Also you really don't want to keep static references to Activities as they will prevent the garbage collector from freeing up memory when it is needed.

Comment: @BMo I make an application for online store. For example the catalog pages with a list of categories are completely similar. I want to be able to move freely between them. I made the good's card on the basis of the same activity too. It seemed easier for me. Maybe I'll make cart on another activity. But I still need to move between instances of activity with catalog. I have read a lot of topics with a similar problem on this site, but they all advised to avoid this problem within a specific task. Is it really impossible to do what I want?

Comment: At the moment, maybe I can solve the problem using flags. But I don't trust them. I'm afraid to get into a situation when there will be a pair of activities, between which I would not be able to switch by using flags.

Comment: @slayton Static link is a temporary solution. In the future, if I can make a class for easy switching, I plan to do this based on Hashtable

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that you move the catalog pages into a Fragment instead of an Activity? That way you can make multiple instances of the Fragment, each with unique tags and `add()` or `remove()` them at will.

More information can be found at the Android Dev site [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29).

If you are working with something below Android 3.0, remember that you can use the compatibility package to get [Fragment support](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html).

Comment: I work under Android 1.6 in order to avoid compatibility issues on older devices.
Thanks for the Fragments, having considered this solution as an alternate.
In the meantime, I hope it will be possible to find a more direct solution.